Snowflake - Lateral flatten
{
  "area": {
    "id": "TEST1"
    "value": "TEST1"
  }, 
{  "testcom": {
     "conditions": [
     {
        "assignedto": {
          "workphone":NULL
        },
        "isClause":false
     }
    ],   
    "iscritical": true,
    "value": "Conditon"
 }
} 
} 

Hi, the output of json structure is as above
questions answer      isClause
testcom   conditions  FALSE

Need the output as above, i have used the below SQL, not able to get the output as expected, the source column is Variant, can someone please check...
select 
lvl_1.key,
lvl_1.value 
from 
    (
    select 
    parse_json(col1) as src 
    from 
    table1
    )xyz 
,lateral flatten(input => xyz.src) lvl_1,
,lateral flatten(input => lvl_1.value) lvl_2,
,lateral flatten(input => lvl_2.value:isClause) lvl_3


The sample data you provided isn't valid JSON.
You only need to LATERAL FLATTEN when you want to turn one row into multiple rows. You should only need to LATERAL FLATTEN once on the conditions array.

So as noted, your provided string is not JSON.
the first sub object area is missing a comma between id and value
this works though:
select PARSE_JSON('{ "area": {"id": "TEST1", "value": "TEST1"}}');

then after area there is a start of an object, but it is not named, this it valid inside a object, so lets name it missing_name_a
select 
    PARSE_JSON('{ 
        "area": {"id": "TEST1", "value": "TEST1"},
        "missing_name_a" : {  
            "testcom": {
                "conditions": [
                    { "assignedto": { "workphone":NULL }, "isClause":false }
                ],   
                "iscritical": true,
                "value": "Conditon"
            }
        } 
    } ') as json

this is valid JSON also.
now if we turn that into a CTE we can select from it, and show how to access the only array in the data:
with cte_json_data as (
select 
    PARSE_JSON('{ 
        "area": {"id": "TEST1", "value": "TEST1"},
        "missing_name_a" : {  
            "testcom": {
                "conditions": [
                    { "assignedto": { "workphone":NULL }, "isClause":false }
                ],   
                "iscritical": true,
                "value": "Conditon"
            }
        } 
    } ') as json
)
select j.*
    ,j.json:missing_name_a:testcom:conditions
from cte_json_data as j

now we can FLATTEN that array:
with cte_json_data as (
select 
    PARSE_JSON('{ 
        "area": {"id": "TEST1", "value": "TEST1"},
        "missing_name_a" : {  
            "testcom": {
                "conditions": [
                    { "assignedto": { "workphone":NULL }, "isClause":false }
                ],   
                "iscritical": true,
                "value": "Conditon"
            }
        } 
    } ') as json
)
select j.*
    ,a.value
from cte_json_data as j
    ,table(flatten(input=>j.json:missing_name_a:testcom:conditions)) as a

so to access isClause you:
with cte_json_data as (
select 
    PARSE_JSON('{ 
        "area": {"id": "TEST1", "value": "TEST1"},
        "missing_name_a" : {  
            "testcom": {
                "conditions": [
                    { "assignedto": { "workphone":NULL }, "isClause":false }
                ],   
                "iscritical": true,
                "value": "Conditon"
            }
        } 
    } ') as json
)
select j.*
    ,a.value:isClause as is_clause
from cte_json_data as j
    ,table(flatten(input=>j.json:missing_name_a:testcom:conditions)) as a


but those objects can be pushed into FLATTEN if you do not know the object names..
but it is gross:
with cte_json_data as (
select 
    PARSE_JSON('{ 
        "area": {"id": "TEST1", "value": "TEST1"},
        "missing_name_a" : {  
            "testcom": {
                "conditions": [
                    { "assignedto": { "workphone":NULL }, "isClause":false }
                ],   
                "iscritical": true,
                "value": "Conditon"
            }
        } 
    } ') as json
)
select
    m.key as questions
    ,a.key as answer
    ,aa.value:isClause as is_clause
from cte_json_data as j
    ,table(flatten(input=>j.json:missing_name_a)) as m
    ,table(flatten(input=>m.value)) as a
    ,table(flatten(input=>a.value)) as aa

gives:

